# cordova1.6.1 with error : cordova-android.js: Line 3558 : JSCallback Error: Request failed

Tags: cordova

first load local html:

```
String url ="file:///android_asset/www/login-mobile.html";
this.loadUrl(url);
```

phonegap loaded successfully in login-mobile.html.

but...
when I click the login button in login-mobile.html , then trigger the click event with code :

```
document.location = "http://192.168.84.86:8080/static/mobile-demo/phonegap/phonegap.html";
or 
$("#loginForm").attr("action","http://192.168.84.86:8080/static/mobile-    demo/phonegap/phonegap.html");
document.loginForm.submit();
```

then phonegap load with the error below:

```
D/CordovaLog(13261): http://192.168.84.101:8686/maw-home/res/js/cordova-  android.js: Line 3558 : JSCallback Error: Request failed.
```

as far as I know, there is something wrong with XHR (cordova/plugin/android/callback).
but i don't know that why?

thanks a lot.

Comment: is space between your url is for real or a typo

Answer (score 0):

complements:
the logic is simple just :
after login  validation, and direct to another page using cordova-1.6.1.

so I find there is a way could be feasible: 
simulate the a tag href handling mechanism with js.

```
var theTarget = document.getElementById('alink'); 
var clickevent = document.createEvent('Event');
clickevent.initEvent('click', true, false);
theTarget.target = "_blank";
theTarget.href = "http://192.168.84.86:8080/static/mobile-demo/phonegap/phonegap.html";
theTarget.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
```

it direct to phonegap.html and load cordova correctly.

so that's why?  and there is any other way to instead of this, because after after validation, I want to post data to the page (phonegap.html).